# Replace space between html tags only

Tags: regex, html, replace

I have a string like

```
var x = "<html><head>  <title>Hello!</title> </head> <body> <div class=”div1”> "+
"<h1>This is a headline!</h1> "+
"<br><img src=”header-image.png”>  </div>  "+
"<div class=”div2”>  <a href=”http://www.google.com”> </a>  </div>"+
"<div class='div3'></div>  </body>  </html>";
```

The output should be

```
x = "<html><head><title>Hello!</title></head><body><div class=”div1”>"+
"<h1>This is a headline!</h1>"+
"<br><img src=”header-image.png”></div>"+
"<div class=”div2”><a href=”http://www.google.com”></a></div>"+
"<div class='div3'></div></body></html>";
```

In the output i should not have any spaces between > and < tags only.

If there is any space between element and property, it should be intact.
If i have below text

```
input : <a href='www.google.com'> Click Here </a>  <br/><span>  </span>
```

output should be

```
<a href='www.google.com'> Click Here </a><br/><span></span>
```

Means only the space between closing and opening tags sgould be replaced by empty string "".

I tried

```
x = x.replace(/>( )</g,"")
```

and the out put is

```
"<html><head>  <title>Hello!</title/headbodydiv class=”div1”h1>This is a headline!</h1><br><img src=”header-image.png”>  </div><div class=”div2”>    <a href=”http://www.google.com”></a></div><div class='div3'></div>  </body>  </html>"
```

I am still getting some spaces in between the tags.
Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply this regex and replace by `empty string`.

```
(?<=>)\s*
```

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/35

Edit:

Seems like lookbehin dis not supported.use

```
>\s*
```

and replace by `>`.

Comment: Its not working. throwing an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=>)\s*/: Invalid group`

Comment: got it, but i need to replace it with `>`

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would replace all the spaces which are present in-between `>`, `<` symbols(included) with `><`

```
x.replace(/>\s+</g, "><")
```

OR

```
x.replace(/>[ \t]+</g, "><")
```

Use `trim()` function to remove all leading and trailing spaces.

```
> s.replace(/>\s+</g, "><").trim()
'<a href=\'www.google.com\'> Click Here </a><br/><span></span>'
```

**Example:**

```
> var s = "<a href='www.google.com'> Click Here </a>  <br/><span>  </span>"
undefined
> s.replace(/>\s+</g, "><")
'<a href=\'www.google.com\'> Click Here </a><br/><span></span>'
```

Comment: If there is some text in between a link like `<a href=''> click here</a>`, then the out put in all theses cases is `<a>clickhere</a>`. but what i want is `<a> click here</a>`

Answer (score 0):

or use this pattern

```
(?<=>) +(?=<)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/190)

Comment: throwing an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=>) +(?=<)/: Invalid group`